# How to fix "Thread 1: fatal error: index out of range" error

Tags: swift

I keep getting the error `fatal error: index out of range` from func `getAnswer` in its first line and also in other parts of my app I am getting delegate error too. I checked the whole code and it seems ok but idk what is the problem.

This is the section form models in mvc design which calculate the process

```
struct RealMadridBrain{
    var score = 0
    var questionNumber = 0
    
    let realTrivias = [
        question(a: ["8", "23", "56"], q: "What Jersey Number Did David Beckham Wear When He Played For Madrid?", correctAnswer: "23", falseAnswer: "8"),
        question(a: ["MNU", "Sporting", "Porto"], q: "What Team Was Cristiano Ronaldo On Before He Transferred To Real Madrid In 2009?", correctAnswer: "MNU", falseAnswer: "Sporting"),
        question(a: ["6", "8", "4"], q: "What Number Does Toni Kroos Wear For The Club?", correctAnswer: "8", falseAnswer: "6")        
    ]
    
    func getAnswer() -> [String] {
        return realTrivias[questionNumber].answer
    }
    
    func getScore() -> Int {
        return score
    }
    
    func getQuestionText() -> String {
        let text = realTrivias[questionNumber].question
        return text
    }
    
    mutating func checkAnswer(_ userAnswer: String) -> Bool {
        let richtigAntwort = realTrivias[questionNumber].rightAnswer
        //let falschAntwort = realTrivias[questionNumber].wrongAnswer
        if userAnswer == richtigAntwort {
            score += 1
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    mutating func getNextQuestion() {
        if questionNumber < realTrivias.count {
            questionNumber += 1
            print(realTrivias.count)
//            print(questionNumber)
        } else if questionNumber == realTrivias.count {
            questionNumber = 0
        } else {
            questionNumber = 0
        }
    }
}
```

This is the section in controllers which fetches data and shows it

```
class RealMadridViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var qText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var optOneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optTwoButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    var realMadridBrain = RealMadridBrain()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 170, y: 420, width: 52, height: 52)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.setImage(UIImage(named:"Done"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(thumbsUpButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func thumbsUpButtonPressed() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle!
        
        let userGotItRight = realMadridBrain.checkAnswer(userAnswer)
        
        if userGotItRight { // == realMadridBrain.rightAnswer()
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        } else if userGotItRight { // == realMadridBrain.wrongAnswer()
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
        
        realMadridBrain.getNextQuestion()
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
        let tu = realMadridBrain.getAnswer()
        qText.text = realMadridBrain.getQuestionText()
        optOneButton.setTitle(tu[0], for: .normal)
        optTwoButton.setTitle(tu[1], for: .normal)
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(realMadridBrain.getScore())"
        optOneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optTwoButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToResult" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! RealMadridFinalVC
            destinationVC.scoreValue = "Your Final Score Is: \(realMadridBrain.getScore())"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic in getNextQuestion is wrong and is the cause of the crash. Think about, what value is `count` and what is the largest possible index value in your array?

Answer (score 0):

The description of the error is enough for you to know what it is about.

The element you are trying to access in the function `getAnswer()` does not exist.

Your array has three elements, so their indexes are 0, 1 and 2.
Print your `questionNumber` at the beginning of the crashing function to see current index, on which the element in array does not exist. Then find in the other functions all the places where you changed the value of the `questionNumber`, you must have done it wrong in some of them.